# Can I list my own smart contract NFT items on other platforms?

Tags: nft, opensea

I am a bit confused cause I see everyone having tutorials on creating their own marketplace AND in OpenSea I don't see a list button only a create button.

I want to create my own smart contract to mint NFTs.
Can I list already minted NFTs on other marketplaces?
Or is a marketplace tied to just a singular smart contract, because this is what it seems to be implied by the demand for NFT marketplaces.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when you deploy the contract and mint your NFTs you will be able to visit the contract address on i.e. OpenSea and all the minted NFTs will be displayed. There is a testnet version of opensea [here](https://testnets.opensea.io/) that you can use to test what ever it is you are envisioning.

Comment: Does my smart contract's code/royalty split/ect get respected? I assume so since it has to still transfer on the blockchain but I wonder how OpenSea tries to collect their royalties or commission if I'm using my own smart contract

Comment: Opensea is just an interface to interact with contracts. Any contract that is erc721 compliant can be viewed on opensea. So, yes, all opensea does is call functions from your contract (assuming it is erc721 compliant) its rather simple